# keeping entire rows after applying groupby with a certain method

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows :
**data_frame:**

```
column_A column_B, column_C
  2        3        5            row= 0
  2        3        6            row= 1
  3        4        2            row= 2
  3        4        9            row= 3
```

what am trying to do is to check the rows that have same values for their **column_A** and their **column_B**, and get the maximum value for each group obtained:
To be more precise: in my exemple I would like to get the row 1 and row 3.
So the expected output should be:

```
column_A column_B, column_C
  2        3        6            row= 1
  3        4        9            row= 3
```

I tried to apply **groupby** with **max method** to **column_C**: it seems to work but What i got as output is column_C. Here is my code:

```
test_df=pd.DataFrame([[2,3,5],[2,3,6],[3,4,2],[3,4,9]],columns=['column_A','column_B','column_C'])
result= test_df.groupby(['column_A','column_B'], sort=False)['column_C'].max()
print(result)
```

and here is the result

```
column_A  column_B
2         3           6
3         4           9
Name: column_C, dtype: int64
```

I know why I have a serie ( since I apply max method on the column_C ), but i couldn't figure out a way to get the corresponding rows instead of only getting column_C values.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sort_values` +`drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('column_C').drop_duplicates(['column_A','column_B'],keep='last')
Out[186]: 
   column_A  column_B  column_C
1         2         3         6
3         3         4         9
```